# Change the Session Variable Output

Tags: dreamweaver, session-variables

I am using Dreamweaver CS5 with Coldfusion 9 to build a dynamic website. I have a MS Access Database that stores login information which includes ID, FullName, FirstName, LastName, Username, Pawword, AcessLevels.

My question is this:
I currently have session variable to track the Username when it is entered into the login page. However I would like to use that Username to pull the User's FullName to display throughout the web pages and use for querying data. How do I change the session variable to read that when they are not entering their FullName on the login page but only Username and password.

I have listed my login information code below if there is any additional information needed please let me know.

This is the path for which the FullName values reside DataSource "Access" Table "Logininfo" Field "FullName" I want the FullName to be unique based on the Username submitted from the Login page.

I apologize in advance for any rookie mistake I may have made I am new to this but learning fast! Ha.

```
<cfif IsDefined("FORM.username")>
  <cfset MM_redirectLoginSuccess="members_page.cfm">
  <cfset MM_redirectLoginFailed="sorry.cfm">
  <cfquery  name="MM_rsUser" datasource="Access">
  SELECT FullName, Username,Password,AccessLevels FROM Logininfo WHERE Username=<cfqueryparam value="#FORM.username#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_clob" maxlength="50"> AND Password=<cfqueryparam value="#FORM.password#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_clob" maxlength="50">
  </cfquery>
  <cfif MM_rsUser.RecordCount NEQ 0>
    <cftry>
      <cflock scope="Session" timeout="30" type="Exclusive">
        <cfset Session.MM_Username=FORM.username>
        <cfset Session.MM_UserAuthorization=MM_rsUser.AccessLevels[1]>
      </cflock>
      <cfif IsDefined("URL.accessdenied") AND false>
        <cfset MM_redirectLoginSuccess=URL.accessdenied>
      </cfif>
      <cflocation url="#MM_redirectLoginSuccess#" addtoken="no">
      <cfcatch type="Lock">
        <!--- code for handling timeout of cflock --->
      </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
  </cfif>
  <cflocation url="#MM_redirectLoginFailed#" addtoken="no">
  <cfelse>
  <cfset MM_LoginAction=CGI.SCRIPT_NAME>
  <cfif CGI.QUERY_STRING NEQ "">
    <cfset MM_LoginAction=MM_LoginAction & "?" & XMLFormat(CGI.QUERY_STRING)>
  </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Comment: You asked the same question in the Adobe Dreamweaver Application Development forum and got an answer two hours before @Danilo Celic took the trouble to reply. You should have marked your question as having been solved to avoid others wasting time trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like the query is already pulling FullName, so if you want a session variable that contains the value of FullName.

You have this code:

Change it to something like the following (should work haven't sued CF in a while, so based on memory, not tested)

```
<cflock scope="Session" timeout="30" type="Exclusive">
    <cfset Session.MM_Username=FORM.username>
    <cfset Session.MM_UserAuthorization=MM_rsUser.AccessLevels[1]>
    <cfset Session.FullName=MM_rsUser.FullName[1]>
</cflock>
```

That will add Session.FullName, and you can reference that elsewhere in your site. It should be present on any page after the user has logged in, so you'd have to check for it's existence on pages that don't require log in before using that value.

Please note: the code you're using is auto-generated by a Dreamweaver log in server behavior, and it's quite possible that the changes I'm suggesting will break the inspection or reapplication of that server behavior. If that happens, then you may be able to recover by removing the added line of code and the re-adding it after making any changes you you need to make. You may need to make sure that FullName is in the query SELECT statement to make sure that FullName will be available.